# How to get the 3rd value from Google Apps Script ContactsApp.Month enum

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, enums

Folks, I must be drawing a blank here. I need to get an enum value by the index of the enum value. For this call

```
myContact.addDate(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY,
                                   ContactsApp.Month.APRIL, 19, 1980);
```

Here month is an enum of JANUARY, FEBRUARY, etc. and this code sets the month to April.  But I know the month as a number, 1-12. I don't know how to get the correct Month enum value based on the number of the month.  How do I do this in JavaScript?  Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Comment: This is an example out of the documentation `var birthday = contacts[0].addDate(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY,
                                   ContactsApp.Month.APRIL, 19, 1950);` . It came from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#adddatelabel-month-day-year)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an associative object that you define to convert the month number to the enum:

```
const months = ContactsApp.Month;
const monthToEnum = {
  1: months.JANUARY,
  2: months.FEBRUARY,
   ...
};
```

And then consume it as

```
var monthEnum = monthToEnum[monthNumber];
```

Comment: That is a great answer and it works.  Brilliant!  Thank you.